# Press a button and it appears somewhere else on the screen

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have this code so it changes location once but then stays there when you still touch

```
- (IBAction)fade {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [button setAlpha: 0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [button setAlpha: 1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    button.center = CGPointMake(152 + 16,326 + 16);
    button.center = CGPointMake(200 + (kPlatformWidth/2),300 + (kPlatformHeight/2));
}
```

How to make it go to a random location from here?

Comment: first of all... why do you not use block-based animations?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use beginAnimations:context:

To quote the docs:

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use
>   the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

You should use the new methods of the form animateWithDuration:animations:

As for how to make the button move to a random location, use arc4random_uniform to calculate new x and y positions and use those values as the destination of your view's center.